# moving object on moving object with SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

i have 1 moving(floating) object with method moveByX(). There is second one that can jump. When i jump on moving object i need to move on it(with it) instead of staying on same position and fall down. Is there any build-in method in physics body or sprite kit?

Comment: You should post your code. If don't use physics, you can just make the jumping object a child of the moving object and it will follow it around at an offset. With physics you'd have to manually add the change in position (difference or velocity) of the moving object to the position of the object whose movement should be relative to the moving object.

Comment: Sounds like a job for gravity and friction.

Comment: I am attaching a tutorial that has a sprite jump on a platform.  The only difference is your platform can move.  The physics and such is all set up to handle any movement you add to the platform.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/63229/make-game-like-mega-jump-spritekit-part-12